# ContactsContract.Contacts query for specific account

Tags: android, contactscontract

Is there an efficient query to find all aggregate contacts for a specific account name & type?

The `ContactsContract.Contacts` table has the `IN_VISIBLE_GROUP` column which is effective for contact group membership. So, if the user has selected various group memberships for accounts, this column will be set.

There does not appear to be any equivalent in-visible-account column. However, the Android contacts app allows selecting a specific account to view without tapping "customize" and selecting groups. Doing this updates the `ContactsContract.Settings` table. The effect does not appear to reach the `Contacts` table.

I would like to be able to do one query and get one cursor back that has exactly the right set of aggregate (meaning from the Contacts table) contacts. Is this possible?

Comment: It appears that the Settings table is improperly used by the Android contacts app. Once you choose "customize", it appears to never update Settings.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP again, rendering the table useless for this purpose. I've observed this on several devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> find all aggregate contacts for a specific account name & type

`Contacts` are account specific, they're combined of multiple `RawContacts`, each can be saved on a different `Account`.

You can query for all the `RawContacts` for a specific `Account`:

```
Cursor c = cr.query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, 
   new String[]{ RawContacts._ID, RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts._ID, ... },
   RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = '" + accountName + "' AND " + RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = '" + accountType + "'", null, null);
```

If you want `Contacts` you can put all contact-ids you found in the above query in an array, and query on `Contacts` table:

```
Cursor c = cr.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
   new String[]{ Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ... },
   Contacts._ID + " IN (" + arrayOfIds + ")", null, null);
```

Comment: I gave you +1 because, in theory, I think your answer works. I considered this but didn't try it because I am concerned about the enormous potential size of "arrayOfIds". Do you think this is not a problem both for query limitations and speed efficiency?

Comment: I have something similar in my app, in rare cases there can be an issue with MySQL query size limitations, but that can be worked around by performing the second query in large batches, with speed I had no issues

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll mark this as the right answer because I doubt google provided for any better alternatives.